# Getting error in python with characters from word document

Tags: python, django

I have this text which is entered in text box

```
‘f’fdsfs’`124539763~!@#$%^’’;’””::’
```

I am coverting to json and then it comes as

```
"\\u2018f\\u2019fdsfs\\u2019`124539763~!@#$%^\\u2019\\u2019;\\u2019\\u201d\\u201d::\\u2019e"
```

Now when i am writing the csv file then i get this error

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2018' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

`csv.writer(data)`

I tried all  `data.encode('utf-8')` `data.decode('unicode-escape')` but didn't work

Comment: Works for me using Python 2.7.3: `x = "\\u2018f\\u2019fdsfs..."; j = json.loads('"' + x + '"'); print j.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: his problem is with the csv writing

Comment: There is some funky stuff going with your input as well. \u2019 corresponds to this character  http://en.glyphwiki.org/wiki/u2018f

Comment: or its the funny quote :P http://en.glyphwiki.org/wiki/u2018   (the f isnt part of the unicode ... unicode is always 4 chars after the u afaik)

Comment: My mistake. But unicode is not always 4 chars. It appears so because the current Unicode representation is same as UTF-16 that covers most of the characters. Many characters are not covered by 16bits so you need to use UTF-32(32 bits code point) or couple of UTF-16 code points to represent the character. If you use UTF-32 notation it is 5 chars. 16bit standard has given rise to some crazy solutions like surrogates etc, well that is for another day. :)

Comment: should have narrowed it down to pythons unicode implementation  ... at least I have never seen 5 character unicode in python :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

csv module does not support unicode  use https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv instead

although im not sure \u2018 is part of the utf-8 charset

```
x = "\\u2018f\\u2019fdsfs..."; j = json.loads('"' + x + '"'); print j.encode('cp1252')
‘f’fdsfs...
```

note that it is being **encoded as cp1252**

```
>>> import unicodecsv as csv #https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv
>>> x = "\\u2018f\\u2019fdsfs..."; j = json.loads('"' + x + '"');
>>> with open("some_file.csv","wb") as f:
...      w = csv.writer(f,encoding="cp1252")
...      w.writerow([j,"normal"])
...
>>>
```

here is the csv file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/m4gta1o9vg8tfap/some_file.csv

Comment: i tried the UnicodeWriter as mentioned here as well http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv-examples but i get the same error

Comment: all I know is ive used the one I linked to and it worked well ... also note that you need to encode it as cp1252 ... although you might be able to use the one there if you specify the correct encoding (cp1252)

Comment: try pasting that weired characters in MS word and then use those to check. because MS word is adding the weired characters